# Element-wise sum of arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

How do I compute element-wise sum of the Arrays?

```
val a = new Array[Int](5)
val b = new Array[Int](5)
// assign values
// desired output: Array -> [a(0)+b(0), a(1)+b(1), a(2)+b(2), a(3)+b(3), a(4)+b(4)]

a.zip(b).flatMap(_._1+_._2)
```

> missing parameter type for expanded function

Comment: It should be `a.zip(b).map(x => x._1 + x._2)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
a.zip(b).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
```

Answer (score 16):

When you use an underscore as a placeholder in a function definition, it can only appear once (for each function argument position, that is, but in this case `flatMap` takes a `Function1`, so there's only one). If you need to refer to an argument more than once, you can't use the placeholder syntax—you'll need to give the argument a name.

As the other answers point out, you can use `.map { case (x, y) => x + y }` or the tuple accessor version, but it's also worth noting that if you want to avoid a bunch of tuple allocations in an intermediate collection, you can write the following:

```
scala> (a, b).zipped.map(_ + _)
res5: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Here `zipped` is a method that's available on pairs of collections that has a special `map` that takes a `Function2`, which means the only tuple that gets created is the `(a, b)` pair. The extra efficiency probably doesn't matter much in most cases, but the fact that you can pass a `Function2` instead of a function from pairs means the syntax is often a little nicer as well.

Comment: I've always thought that `_` can be used once for each parameter, and it's not because of parentheses. There is only one parameter in original example which is a tuple, compiler message is just misleading, or it's trying to say that it can't infer parameter type for function with two parameters. `a.zip(b).map((_:(Int, Int))._1 + (_:(Int, Int))._2)` shows real error (`flatMap' won't work here for an obvious reason, return type is wrong). Am I wrong here?

Comment: meanwhile this code `(a.zip(b), a.zip(b)).zipped.map(_._1 + _._2)` compiles,   while this `(a.zip(b), a.zip(b)).zipped.map(_._1.+(_._2))` doesn't, so you are right about parentheses, only `+` is not a syntactic sugar in this case, it works differently.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Ah, thanks for pointing out that the first part of my answer didn't focus on the most relevant info here. I've just updated it.

Comment: Could you say more, Travis, on `which means the only tuple that gets created is the (a, b) pair.`? How is `(List(1), List(2)).zipped` different than `List(1).zip( List(2) )`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Take `(0 to 1000).zip(0 to 1000).map(p => p._1 + p._2)` vs. `(0 to 1000, 0 to 1000).zipped.map(_ + _)`. The first creates a thousand tuple objects and the second creates one.

Answer (score -1):

```
// one D Array    
val x = Array(1, 2, 3, 40, 55)    
val x1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 40, 55)    
x.indices.map(i=>x(i)+ x(i) )  

// TWo D Array    
val x1= Array((3,5), (5,7))    
val x = Array((1,2), (3,4))    
x.indices.map(i=>( x(i)._1 + x1(i)._1, x(i)._2 + x1(i)._2))
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service, by adding some explanation to this code-only answer. (Downvote not by me.)

Comment: Your 1st example ignores the `x1` array and just doubles the `x` array. Your 2nd example is not a 2-dimensional array, it's just an `Array` of tuples.