# How to get the sum of two elements in a list of Arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, sum

Hello and thanks in advance for taking the time reading this.

I am writing a piece of code in Scala to read a data file, and produce a couple of aggregations. For the sake of simplicity let's assume the contents are something like the following(the records are tab delimited):

> 01/12/2015    JACK    M   21XYZ   56  200
>
> 01/14/2015    JOHN    M   22ABS   34  145

I want to multiply the last two numbers and store them along with the second item (Name) and then run some statistics `(min, max, top 10, etc.)`

Steps I have taken so far:

1- Read the file

```
    val dat = scala.io.Source.fromFile("abs.txt")
```

2- Put the contents in a list

```
    val datList = try dat.getLines.toList finally dat.close
```

3- Split each string into an array of Strings

```
    val datArray = datList.map(_.split('\t'))
```

after these steps I have an array of Array of strings. I am stuck at this point. I don't know how I can calculate the multiplication of the last two elements of each array and store the results in a map and have the name as key.

When I try something like

```
    val res = datArray.map(x => x(4).toInt * x(5).toDouble)
```

it returns a Unit and I cannot do anything with it.

I would appreciate it if you can shed some light.

I found something similar in the following link, however that is between two separate arrays which seems to be simpler.

[Element-wise sum of arrays in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064883/element-wise-sum-of-arrays-in-scala)

Thanks,

Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly doesn't "return a Unit". `res` is an array of doubles.
You forgot about the name though, but that's easy to fix:

```
 val res = datArray.map(x => x(1) -> x(4).toInt * x(5).toDouble)
```

Now, you have a sequence of tuples, `Seq[(String, Double)]`, where first element is the name, and the second one is the product you are after.

You can do all kinds of things with this list:

- Convert it into a map `name` -> `score`:  `res.toMap` (beware: if you have duplicate entries with the same name, only the last one of each set will be kept)
- Find the entry with the smallest score: `val (name, score) = res.minBy(_._2)`
- Find entry with largest score: `val (name, score) = res.maxBy(_._2)
- Find total of all scores: `res.map(_._2).sum`
- Find top ten entries: `res.sortBy(-_._2).take(10)`
- Combine scores with the same name, and make a map like in the first item, but with values being total scores for each name: `res.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)`
- etc ...

Comment: Thanks Dima. It seems I was almost there as jvwilge mentioned. Now I will continue to get the sum of the records by name, and for this I don't think map is a good idea. Like you mentioned only the last one is kept in case there are duplicate keys

Comment: @Moe take a look at the last item in the list ... I might have added it after you wrote your comment. It does what you describe.

Comment: I Wish I'd seen your comment sooner :)). I came up with the following but I like your version better: for ((k, v) <- res) {
   m += k -> (v + m.getOrElse(k, 0d))
  }

Comment: yeah ... mutable vars are evil. You should learn to avoid them. 99% of the time, they are not needed, and I promise, you'll go to appreciate the benefits of not having them

Comment: You are right. BTW both solutions works in case I am processing only one file. But what if I have multiple files there might be duplicate names in other files with different scores. I am struggling to calculate the total score per person across multiple files

Comment: `file1.getLines ++ file2.geLines` ... then as before

Comment: anyway that can be done in a look. I mean concatenating the lines from files in a directory

Comment: I ended up creating a function to collect the records and then calling the function like dataFiles.map(file => collect(file.getAbsolutePath)).flatten

Comment: you can use `flatMap` instead of `map.flatten`

Answer (score 0):

`val res = datArray.map(x => (x(1), x(4).toInt * x(5).toDouble)).toMap`

You were almost there, you returned a list with the values. You should convert it to pairs (by adding a key). A pair looks like `(key, value)` and then call a toMap.